# Struggling to display Smart Contract information in web page using react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

```
function App(){
const [PopulateStudent] = useState(0);
const handleGet = asnyc (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const result = await Certificate.methids.PopulateStudent("parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter3", "parameter4").call();
console.log(result)
}
return(
<div className="App">
<header>
<button onClick = {handleGet} type = "button">Fill</button>
</header>
</div>
);
}
export default App;
```

This is my code in App.js. I am trying to call the `PopulateStudent` function from the solidity Smart Contract. It has 4 parameters and is shown below.

```
constructor() public{
PopulateStudent("string", "string", int, int)
Fill();
}
function PopulateStudent(string memory _name, string memory _surname, uint _exam, uint _center) public { 
students[1] = Student({name :_name, surname: _surname, examNumber: _exam, center:_center, qualification:Qualification.Bachelor, level:Level.one});
}
```

When I run the code in the browser, and click the `Fill` button I can't get a value to display. The only operation I see when I view the Console log under InspectElement is `Object { }` when i click `Fill`.
I am new to solidity and React.js so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question and share the contents of the `PopulateStudent()` Solidity function, including the state modifiers (whether it's `view`, `pure` or none), definition of return value (e.g. `returns (bool)`)... According to the function name, I'm just assuming you'll have to make a transaction using the `.send()` JS method, not just a read-only `.call()`.

Comment: @PetrHejda I have edited the question to include all the information in the Smart Contract that is related to the PopulateStudent. The reason I used `.call()` is because it is only supposed to read the information from the contract and this shouldn't cost eth. I don't know if any of this information will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main types of operations when you're interacting with smart contracts. A (read-write) transaction and a (read-only) call.

The `PopulateStudent()` solidity function requires a transaction, because it **modifies** the contract state (**saves** the newly created `Student` struct to the contract storage).

If the `students` property (to which the `PopulateStudent()` stores) is **`public`**, you can call its autogenerated getter function (autogenerated - it doesn't need to be in your contract). For example:

```
// returns `students[1]`
const result = await Certificate.methods.students(1).call();
```